# Why can't pointer value be a good label to refer object in memory space?

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

For example,

```
int x = 10;
```

We know that identifier `x` acts like a label which refers object that stores the value  `10`. But why can't `&x` also be called as a label which refers the same object? `&x` is an address value of the whole `int` object which stores the value `10`. So I think identifier `x` and `&x` has no difference in playing a role as a label of the object. Therefore, I believe this gives a good reason to say that `&x` is an `lvalue`. Because according to ISO C11 6.3.2.1, it says that

> lvalue is an expression that potentially designates an object.

But why isn't the pointer value `&x` an `lvalue`?

Comment: Because that's the way the language was designed.

Comment: Your address is not yourself.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath But I guess the same logic applies to `x`

Comment: I don't think `&x` designates an object but I'd have to look up the exact definition of "object".

Comment: Because you cannot update the object through the *expression* `&x` - you can't write `&x = 11;`.  That's why `&x` is not an lvalue expression.

Comment: @JohnBode But doesn't designating an object means refering to the chunk of memory, not refering to the value stored in the chunk of memory?

Comment: @Jin:  One more time - you can assign a new value to `x`.  You cannot assign a new value to `&x`.  That's the difference.  The *expression* `&x` does not designate an object in memory - it designates an *address* of an object in memory, and you *cannot modify an address*.  `&x` may not be the target of an assignment, thus it *cannot* be an lvalue.

Comment: @JohnBode That clarifies everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because &x isn't a label, it's a pointer to a labeled value.

To help you understand why this is important, I'm going to give an explanation of the different types of references:

labels - also called 'aliases' or 'names', they identify some value or object. in a dynamically-typed language, the value or object they identify can change; whereas in a statically-typed language, it stays the same. an example of a label-type reference in C would be `int x;`

pointer - a pointer identifies the address of some value or object. this is useful for implementing aliasing (having multiple references to the same object). an example of a pointer-type reference in C would be `int *x;` or `&x`

handle - a handle is a unique identifier (usually an integer) for some value or object. like pointers, they allow for aliasing; but a handle cannot be dereferenced like a pointer. This is extremely useful because it can be used to hide the underlying implementation of a data structure and allow for a memory manager to safely rearrange memory (eg. defragmentation) to improve cache coherency and boost performance. an example of a handle-type reference in C would be the `int` value returned by POSIX `open` function.

Off-topic: In Golang, when you try to assign to the member of a pointer-type object, it's automatically dereferenced; so there's no need for a `->` operator. For `vec2 *v`, `v.x` would be interpreted as `v[0].x`.

Comment: Wow thanks for giving explanation of different types of references!